# facing isssue while deleting a target comment

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

When I click the delete button, the correct comment `id` and text is logged in the console.
But the comment before it is deleted.
This implies that the target `id` changes between click and deletion.

Toggler component to toggle the delete button - 
list post is mapped to create:
`component{post title, body, likes, comment}`.

code for comment component:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "../../styles/posts/postComponent.scss";   
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { removeComment } from "../../redux/actions/@posts";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Comment = ({ admin, auth, post_id, removeComment, comments }) => {
const commentList = comments
? comments.map(comment => {
    return (
      <div className='c-img-text'>
        <img
          className='c-img'
          height={"40px"}
          src={comment.avatar}
          alt='pic'
          onClick={() => console.log(comment.avatar)}
        />
        <div className='c-nt'>
          <a href='#' className='c-n'>
            {comment.name}
          </a>
          <span className='c-t'>{comment.text.toString()}</span>
          <i className='c-d'>{comment.date}</i>
        </div>

        <Toggler
          auth={auth}
          pst_id={post_id}
          adm_id={admin._id}
          cmt_id={comment._id}
          cmt_user={comment.user}
          removeComment={removeComment}
          cmt_txt={comment.text}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })
 : "";
return (
<Fragment>
  <div className='c-container'>{commentList}</div>
</Fragment>
);
};

  const Toggler = ({
  auth,
  pst_id,
  adm_id,
  cmt_id,
  cmt_txt,
  cmt_user,
  removeComment
  }) => {
  const [showDelete, setShowDelete] = useState(false);
  const deleteComment = cmt_id => {
  removeComment(pst_id, cmt_id);
  console.log(cmt_txt, cmt_id, pst_id);
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={() => setShowDelete(!showDelete)}>
  {auth && adm_id ? adm_id === cmt_user && <div>...</div> : ""}
  {showDelete && (
    <div
      className='c-delete'
      onClick={async () => await deleteComment(cmt_id)}
    >
      icon
    </div>
  )}
</div>
 );
 };

  Comment.propTypes = {
   admin: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   auth: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
   post_id: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   removeComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   comments: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
             return { state };
          };
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { removeComment })(Comment);
```

code for action (redux):

```
//remove comment 
 export const removeComment = (post_id, comment_id) => async dispatch => {
  try {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  const res = await axios.delete(
  `/api/posts/comments/${post_id}/${comment_id}`
  );
   dispatch({
    type: REMOVE_COMMENT,
    payload: { postId: post_id, comments: res.data }
    });
  console.log("from", comment_id);
  } catch (error) {
   console.error(error.message);
   dispatch({
    type: POST_ERROR
  });
  }
};
```

code for backend:

```
  //@route DELETE api/posts/comments/:post_id/:comment_id
  //@desc remove a comment
  //@access Private
  const removeComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.post_id);

    //Pull out comment
    const comment = post.comments.find(
   comment => comment.id === req.params.comment_id
    );
    //make sure comment exists
    if (!comment) {
     res.status(404).json({ error: "Comment does not exist" });
     }

    //check admin
     if (comment.user.toString() !== req.admin.id) {
     return res.status(401).json({ msg: "User not authorized" });
     }

    //Get remove index
    const removeIndex = post.comments
    .map(comment => comment.user.toString())
    .indexOf(req.admin.id);

    post.comments.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    await post.save();

   res.json(post.comments);
   } catch (error) {
   console.error(error.message);
   res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
   };
```

TECHSTACK :mongodb, express, reactjs , nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I changed the removeIndex statement.

```
const removeComment = async (req, res) => {
try {
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.post_id);

//Pull out comment
const comment = post.comments.find(
comment => comment.id === req.params.comment_id
);
//make sure comment exists
if (!comment) {
 res.status(404).json({ error: "Comment does not exist" });
 }

//check admin
 if (comment.user.toString() !== req.admin.id) {
 return res.status(401).json({ msg: "User not authorized" });
 }

//Get remove index
const removeIndex = post.comments.indexOf(comment);

post.comments.splice(removeIndex, 1);
await post.save();

res.json(post.comments);
} catch (error) {
console.error(error.message);
res.status(500).send("Server Error");
}
};
```